# "tapping into the pulsing"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Human beings are social animals, linked together by shared beliefs and values. This is both a weakness and a strength. Brands use this fact against us by **tapping into the pulsing collective mass** of our shared fears, hopes, desires and anxieties and the consumer blind spots which offer the greatest opportunity for exploitation are related to the murky area of emotions and feelings.*

Source: https://www.irishexaminer.com/lifestyle/features/how-to-survive-christmas-463410.html

I would ask you just one question regarding this paragraph. Do you think that the word "pulsing" stands in the context for the noun ("the practice of advertising a product all the time, but increasing the advertising for some periods and reducing it for other periods")? Or is it just the adjective related to "collective mass"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjective most certainly applies to the collective mass. Collective is also an adjective here modifying mass, so there should be a comma after pulsing.

> ...tapping into the pulsing, collective mass of our shared fears, hopes, and desires...